# Calling SharePoint list.amx service throws error - The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, web-services, wcf

Here is my scenario : I am trying to access **SharePoint 2010 list items** via **list.asmx** service. Following is my code and app.config which works on my developer box hosting the SharePoint site

```
var client = new ServiceReferenceSPList.ListsSoapClient();
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "...";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "...";
var result = client.GetListItems("My List", null, query, viewFields, rowLimit, queryOptions, null);

<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="ListsSoap" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" >
        <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm"/>
        </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
    <endpoint address="http://server:port/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ListsSoap"
        contract="ServiceReferenceSPList.ListsSoap" name="ListsSoap" />
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Above code works when its run from SharePoint machine itself. I have SharePoint site on my machine and hence when I run above code it returns list items. However when I try to access SharePoint site hosted on other server on the network it throws error

> **The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Ntlm'. The authentication header received from the server was 'NTLM'**.

I have read few posts around this error but none seems to help.

- [Call SharePoint custom WCF service from within same SharePoint site](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/71297/call-sharepoint-custom-wcf-service-from-within-same-sharepoint-site)
- [SharePoint search web service error (NTLM) when called from HttpHandler](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/4734/sharepoint-search-web-service-error-ntlm-when-called-from-httphandler)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16273032/connect-to-sharepoint-web-service-through-claims-based-ntlm-authentication

I dont think I am facing double hop issue as I am passing credentials and code on development box directly going to SharePoint server. SharePoint 2010 site being accessed in a Claims enabled NTLM auth site.

Please let me know your suggestions to possibly solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to log in to target site manually, with that service account. Seems like the client just can not login to the site at the first time.